# train data shape error in the deep learning model using keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I am creating a Deep Learning model for a multiclass classification problem my model contains 46 unique classes. My **X_train** shape is **(14382, 183)**, & **y_train** is **14382**

Code-

```
#Creating Dummy Variables 
X=pd.get_dummies(X, prefix=list((X.select_dtypes(include=[object])).columns))

#Splitting the dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=10)

model = Sequential()

#adding layers to the model
model.add(Dense(units =367, activation ='relu', input_dim =183))
model.add(Dense(units =182, activation ='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units =182, activation='relu'))


 #output layer
model.add(Dense(46, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001) , metrics = ['accuracy'] )
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size = 50, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

I am facing an error after running the model that is-

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_110 to have shape (46,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How can I solve this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your target shape

Actually it's 1 dimensional so you can leave as is and apply `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss function

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Otherwise, you can one-hot encode it `pd.get_dummies(y).values` (before train test split) and get an y of shape (n_sample, n_class). In this case, you can use `categorical_crossentropy`

```
X = np.random.randint(0,10, (1000,100))
y = pd.get_dummies(np.random.randint(0,3, 1000)).values

model = Sequential([
    Dense(128, input_dim = 100),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: error using sparse_categorical_crossentropy error- Received a label value of -9223372036854775808 which is outside the valid range of [0, 46)

Comment: I add some dummy examples, let me know

Comment: thanks, problem solved 1 upvote but can't vote need 15 reputations anyway thank you very much your solution made my day